# NodeJS: Reading and writing to a shared object from multiple promises

Tags: node.js, concurrency, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to find out if there could be an issue when accessing an object from multiple promises, eg:

```
let obj = {test: 0}
let promisesArr = []

for (let n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
    promisesArr.push(promiseFunc(obj))
}

Promise.all(promisesArr)

// Then the promise would be something like this 
function promiseFunc(obj) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        // read from the shared object
        let read = obj.test
        // write/modify the shared object
        obj.test++
        // Do some async op with the read data
        await asyncFunc(read)
        // resolves and gets called again later
    })
}
```

From what I can see/tested there would not be an issue, it would seem like even though processing is asynchronous, there is no race condition. But maybe I could be missing something.

The only issue that I can see is writing to the object and then doing some I/O op and then read expecting what was written before to still be there

I'm not modifying the object after other async operations only at the start, but there are several promises doing the same. Once they resolve they get called again and the cycle starts over.

Comment: JS is single thread.  if you don't use workers you don't have to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Race conditions in Javascript with multiple asynchronous operations depend entirely upon the application logic of what exactly your doing.

Since you don't show any real code in that regard, we can't really say whether you have a race condition liability here or not.

**There is no generic answer to your question.**

Yes, there can be race conditions among multiple asynchronous operations accessing the same data.

OR

The code can be written appropriately such that no race condition occurs.

It all depends upon the exact and real code and what it is doing.  There is no generic answer.  I can show you code with two promise-based asynchronous operations that absolutely causes a race condition and I can show you code with two promise-based asynchronous operations that does not cause a race condition.  **So, susceptibility to race conditions depends on the precise code and what it is doing and precisely how it is written.**

Pure and simple access to a value in a shared object does not by itself cause a race condition because the main thread in Javascript is single threaded and non-interruptible so any single synchronous Javascript statement is thread-safe by itself.  What matters is what you do with that data and how that code is written.

---

Here's an example of something that is susceptible to race conditions if there are other operations that can also change `shareObj.someProperty`:

```
let localValue = shareObj.someProperty;
let data = await doSomeAsyncOperation();
shareObj.someProperty = localValue + data.someProperty;
```

Whereas, this not cause a race condition:

```
let data = await doSomeAsyncOperation();
shareObj.someProperty = shareObj.someProperty += data.someProperty;
```

The second is not causing its own race condition because it is atomically updating the shared data.  Whereas the first was getting it, storing it locally, then waiting for an asynchronous operation to complete which is an opportunity for other code to modify the shared variable without this local function knowing about it.

FYI, this is very similar to classic database issues.  If you get a value from a database (which is always an asynchronous operation in nodejs), then increment it, then write the value back, that's subject to race conditions because others can be trying to read/modify the value at the same time and you can stomp on each other's changes.  So, instead, you have to use an atomic operation built into the database to update the variable in one atomic operation.

For your own variables in Javascript, the problem is a little bit simpler than the generic database issue because reading and writing to a Javascript variable is atomic.  You just make to make sure you don't hold onto a value that you will later modify and write back across an asynchronous operation.

Comment: Ok, I get what you mean, I think you've answered my question. I've edited the code to show better what is going on. What I was wondering is what you pointed out, the moment you go out to execute async operations there is a chance another function can edit your object. And you should care if you need that data back after that async op right?

Comment: @FranciscoRangel - Yes, nodejs is essentially cooperative multi-tasking, not pre-emptive multi-tasking.  At the point you wait for an asynchronous operation to complete, other code can run and could change any shared state/objects while you're waiting.  You have to anticipate that in your design and how to code that is entirely application specific.  If this has answered your question, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.